# Checking for VC2015 redistributables (no update vs update1 vs update 2) after Windows 7 upgrade to 10

Tags: c#, installation, redistributable, visual-c++-2015

I have some software that checks whether the Visual C++ 2015 x86 redistributable is installed before loading and calling a DLL that needs it. The check is done via interop call to `MsiQueryProductState`, using the following declaration

```
[DllImport("msi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern INSTALLSTATE MsiQueryProductState(string product);
```

and the call is

```
Win32API.MsiQueryProductState("{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}")
```

which used to work, and still does in other machines with Windows 10 and the original, non-updated redistributable installed.

I use VS2015 with Update 2 for C# Windows Desktop development, which includes the redistributable update 2.

A few weeks ago, I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10, and yesterday found out that the check went from returning `INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT` to returning `INSTALLSTATE_UNKNOWN`. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the issue, as I only found out about it after the upgrade.

After googling and finding nothing, I searched the registry and the redistributable installation log file, and I found the following keys

```
{BD9CFD69-EB91-354E-9C98-D439E6091932}
{2e085fd2-a3e4-4b39-8e10-6b8d35f55244}
{B5FC62F5-A367-37A5-9FD2-A6E137C0096F}
{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}
```

but I have not the faintest idea if I'm doing it right - the first two return `INSTALLSTATE_UNKNOWN`, and the latter two return `INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT`. Which works, but I don't know if it's right. I thought all the versions and updates would use the same key.

So, the question I'm trying to ask is: what keys should I be querying in order to know if a compatible version of the Visual C++ 2015 x86 Redistributables is installed, be it no update, update 1 or update 2?

Comment: [This page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/618d32d8-a74f-4a02-b448-18b70d8f8573/vs2015-update-2-rtl-distribution-files-guids?forum=visualstudiogeneral) may be relevant

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that link. It's very similar to what I did, and the author seems to have concluded the same as me (meaning, not too sure). I'll have to run tests on a vanilla Windows installation and see what happens :)

Comment: Crystal ball says that you upgraded from the 32-bit to the 64-bit version of Windows.  So you are now using some 64-bit component to perform this check.  Hard to see why we have to guess at it.  Use the 32-bit component instead.

Comment: Sorry, crystal ball got it wrong :D (is it even possible to upgrade a 32 bit Windows installation to 64 bit? I believed not, but may be wrong)

Win7 was 64 bit and Win10 is 64 bit; the project is the same, and is forcefully 32 bit because of an older (commercial) library that only exists in 32 bit flavor.

I will possibly have to go back to this issue shortly because I am now developing in VS2015 Update 3 and have a production update coming soon.

Thanks :)